# Customize placement of "see ..." part in index using glossaries?

Tags: glossaries

When I use the `glossaries` package to produce the index, the `see` part of an entry appears at the end of an entry after the page numbers. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}
\setglossarystyle{mcolindex}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{term}{name={technical term}, description=\nopostdesc,
  see={term2}}
\newglossaryentry{term2}{name={another term}, description=\nopostdesc}

\begin{document}
First occurrance of \gls{term}, second occurrance of \gls{term}.
First occurance of \gls{term2}.

\newpage

Third occurance of \gls{term}.

\newpage

More \glspl{term}.

\newpage

Even more \glspl{term}.

\printglossary

\end{document}
```

which produces:

```
technical term    1-4, see another
        term
```

But I would like to get:

```
technical term    1-4
     see another term
```

Is that possible to achieve?

Comment: Can you please supply an example to play with?

Comment: No one has any idea on how to do this?

Comment: With `\renewcommand\glsseeformat[3][\seename]{\\*\emph{#1} \glsseelist{#2}}` you can go to the next line, but removing the comma is something more difficult. It could also be a problem if an item has just the “see” entry. Sorry for being late, but I didn't notice you added the code; next time, ping the user leaving the comment, by starting your own comment with `@<username>`

Comment: @egreg  That actually worked quite nicely! The trailing comma I can live with. Could you please turn your comment into an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine `\glsseeformat` so that it goes to a new line

```
\renewcommand\glsseeformat[3][\seename]{%
  \\*% non breaking new line
  \emph{#1} \glsseelist{#2}%
}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}
\setglossarystyle{mcolindex}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{term}{name={technical term}, description=\nopostdesc,
  see={term2}}
\newglossaryentry{term2}{name={another term}, description=\nopostdesc}

\renewcommand\glsseeformat[3][\seename]{%
  \\*% non breaking new line
  \emph{#1} \glsseelist{#2}%
}
\begin{document}
First occurrance of \gls{term}, second occurrance of \gls{term}.
First occurance of \gls{term2}.

\newpage

Third occurance of \gls{term}.

\newpage

More \glspl{term}.

\newpage

Even more \glspl{term}.

\printglossary

\end{document}
```

[image]